# Passing boolean key value from one package to another with kvoptions

Tags: package-writing, package-options, kvoptions

The source document below first writes two packages, each using keys and `kvoptions`; the first package passes a boolean option to the second and calls the second.

Despite the preamble line

```
\usepackage[whether=true]{pkg}
```

in the source document below, the output is always `It's false`, and I see this error in the log:

```
Package more Warning: Value `PKG@whether' is not supported by
(more)                option `whether' on input line 9.
```

What's wrong?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{pkg.sty}
\RequirePackage[debugshow]{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=PKG,prefix=PKG@}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\DeclareBoolOption{whether}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\PassOptionsToPackage{whether=PKG@whether}{more}
\RequirePackage{more}
\end{filecontents}
%%%%
\begin{filecontents}{more.sty}
\RequirePackage[debugshow]{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=MORE,prefix=MORE@}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\DeclareBoolOption{whether}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\ifthenelse{\boolean{MORE@whether}}
  {\newcommand{\sayit}{it's true}}
  {\newcommand{\sayit}{it's false}}
\end{filecontents}
%%%%

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[whether=true]{pkg}

\begin{document}
\sayit
\end{document}
```

*Note:* Of course, the preceding is a MWE of my real situation, where the packages do useful things. More importantly, both real packages take additional boolean keys as well as several string keys.

**One workaround:** The following cures the problem but seems overly complicated to me. Replace the line

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{whether=PKG@whether}{more}
```

with...

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{PKG@whether}}{\newcommand{\newwhether}{true}}{\newcommand{\newwhether}{false}}
\PassOptionsToPackage{whether=\newwhether}{more}
```

... or, in the first of these two lines, a corresponding `\if ... \fi` construction.

**Is there a simpler, more direct, way**, avoiding the need to make a new conditional command — given still that in the actual situation each package will have multiple boolean and string key options?

Comment: My guess is that `\PKG@whether` is not a “string” containing `true` or `false`, but rather a boolean flag.

Comment: Can’t you just do `\ifPKG@whether \PassOptionsToPackage{whether=true}{more} \fi` (note the default boolean is `false`)?

Comment: @RuixiZhang:i I don't want to use the \ifPKG@whether...\fi work-around is that it would be quite awkward in my actual situation, since both packages will have additional Boolean options as well as several string options.

Comment: @RuixiZhang: Since multiple `\PassOptionsToPackage` commands may be used, so may multiple `\ifPKG@boolOptName \PassOptionsToPackage ... \fi` ` commands be used. So please make your 2nd comment above into an answer! It seems to most easily suit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comments into an answer as requested.

When you `\DeclareBoolOption{whether}` in `pkg.sty` with prefix `PKG@`, it creates a boolean flag `\ifPKG@whether` and sets `\PKG@whetherfalse` by default. There are no “strings” such as `true` or `false` created.

I assumed the reasons you used the `\PassOptionsToPackage{...}{more} \RequirePackage{more}` construct was that you had multiple options to be passed to `more.sty`. We want to avoid `\RequirePackage[option]{more} \RequirePackage[otheroption]{more}` because this will produce “conflicting options” error.

It is perfectly fine to use the already created flags and to call `\PassOptionsToPackage` multiple times. Say, you have booleans `whether` and `other` in `more.sty`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{more.sty}
\PassOptionsToPackage{debugshow}{kvoptions}% changed from \RequirePackage[debugshow]{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=MORE,prefix=MORE@}
\DeclareBoolOption{whether}
\DeclareBoolOption[true]{other}% default true
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
...
\end{filecontents}
```

You can structure your `pkg.sty` as follows:

```
\begin{filecontents}{pkg.sty}
\PassOptionsToPackage{debugshow}{kvoptions}% changed from \RequirePackage[debugshow]{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=PKG,prefix=PKG@}
\DeclareBoolOption{whether}
\DeclareBoolOption{other}% default false
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\ifPKG@whether
  \PassOptionsToPackage{whether=true}{more}
\fi

\ifPKG@other
\else
  \PassOptionsToPackage{other=false}{more}
\fi

\RequirePackage{more}
\end{filecontents}
```

You may use `\csname opt@more.sty\endcsname` in the body to check the option list of `more.sty`.

Answer (score 2):

A bool key defines a boolean. For a command you would need something like the choice keys of l3keys.

But you can use the boolean directly in the \RequirePackage:

```
\RequirePackage[whether=\ifPKG@whether true\else false \fi]{more}
```

In `\PassOptionsToPackage` the argument is not expanded, so you would need the standard `\next` method:

```
\edef\next{%
 \noexpand\PassOptionsToPackage{whether=
         \ifPKG@whether true\else false \fi }{more}}

\next
```

Comment: The latter does work in my situation (which will involve intermediate packages, so that the first package `pkg` will not directly call the last one `more`). Is that inherently simpler than the "One workaround" I found and added to the end of my post?

Comment: Is this OK instead? `\ifPKG@whether \def\newwhether{true} \else \def\newwhether{false}\fi` and then `\PassOptionsToPackage{whether=\newwhether}{more}` That is, am I overlooking something problematic with this method?

Comment: @murray But this would waste token space for the temporary `\newwhether` and is no different from `\ifPKG@whether \PassOptionsToPackage{whether=true}{more} \fi`…

Comment: well you should better not use \def without a \newcommand first to check if it is already defined unless you know exactly that the command is specific to your package - which is normally not the case with command containing only letters.

Comment: @RuixiZhang: But in my actual situation I cannot easily use the `\ifPKG@whether\PassOptionsToPackage{whether=true}{more} \fi` method when I'll have multiple boolean keys. Or can I use *multiple* `\PassOptionsToPackage` commands, one for each such key?

Comment: @murray If you mean `\ifPKG@whether \PassOptionsToPackage{whether=true}{more} \else \PassOptionsToPackage{whether=false}{more} \fi`, then yes. I omitted the `\else` branch purely because I assumed you would use defaults, which shortened the code.

Comment: @RuixiZhang: No, I didn't mean multiple `\PassOptionsToPackage` like that. Rather, I meant several separate `\ifPKG@boolOptName \PassOptionsToPackage...\fi` commands, one for each of several different boolean-valued keys. (I do understand the business about the default value being false.)